# In Windows, is a HANDLE an address in a process' VAS or an independent index into something else?

Tags: winapi, handle, hwnd

Simply put, if I were to call some API returning a handle, such as GetActiveWindow(), which would give me a handle of type HWND, what do I get back?  Is it a unique address in the process' VAS, or a unique index into some OS structure?  Or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An opaque integer identifier that has no meaning or use outside the API calls it's designed to work with - IOW, there's no way of knowing most of the time, and most of the time you shouldn't care. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Yes to all of the above. In other words, it varies (widely) by handle type. Some are addresses (often hashed), others are indexes into particular tables, etc.